# Is it possible to generate background API from swagger?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

I know that it is possible to generate front-end (react) code based on Swagger.
I am working with ASP.NET CORE 2.0 and I am wonder if there is possibility to generate my API(Controller) from swagger or at least use part of it such as generating data annotation or etc.

Could you please anyone give advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is through the online [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io). Just paste (or write) your API definition, then select **Generate Server > aspnetcore** (or whatever language you want).

For offline tools
[Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) can generate lots of server stubs and client SDKs based on OpenAPI (Swagger) definitions - including ASP.NET Core 2.0 servers.

Comment: Thank you so much I used "Generate Client" and then "CSharp" , It produced what I want. I can accept your answer after 5 minutes.

Comment: @lewis Just FYI, `csharp` is a client generator. The server generator is `aspnetcore`.